# iOS app looks different on every device, trouble understanding auto layout/constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, mobile-application

I'm trying to create a very basic app but I keep running into this same problem. I'm designing the UI on an iPhone 11 in storyboards and it looks like this[image]

Which is exactly how I would like it to look on every screen size but instead, when I run it on the iPhone 8 simulator or even plug in an iPhone 7, it looks like this: [image]

This is extremely frustrating as I don't know what I'm doing wrong per se. I've tried following the autolayout/constraint instructions from multiple sources but I can't seem to get it to work! Any advice on how to fix this or at least where to look for guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to iOS programming, Constraints can be daunting at first, it happens to everyone. I learnt from these links below. Though they need some patient reading first.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Just remember every view needs 2 things to define its layout, its size and position.

1. Position is the easiest, you can define leading, trailing, top and bottom for any view and we have centerX and centerY as well
2. Size is a little tricky since some views define its own size (Intrinsic Content Size). But if the view doesn't define its own size, they are either defined by their contents (Subviews) or by us (by width and height anchors)